# Why is my AJAX call failing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I am making an AJAX call and sending it to a PHP file. It processes it and it actually does save to the database. So, in reality the AJAX is working. But, when it returns, it apparently reads as an error because I get the alert associated with error message.. Here is my ajax from my javascript file...

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "printMail.php?do=insertExport",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'dtData': JSON.stringify(delTick)},
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                alert("Made it here");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert("Delivery ticket was not saved!");
            }

        });
```

Now, the php is going to be a little weird in that we use an inhouse API for writing to the database... But here it is..

```
  $values = json_decode($_REQUEST['dtData']);
        // var_dump($dtData);
        try {
            $saveExp = $this->dbp->callMethod("exportdeliveryticket", 'saveDeliveryTicket', $values);
            echo json_encode($saveExp);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Failed while saving delivery ticket " . $e);
        }
```

Finally, here is my response through the console...

```
"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Successfully called","data":[{"book":"2",".... etc, etc...
```

Again, it is saving to the database, but yet, js sees it as a failure and I don't see why...

Comment: Since it's a jQuery/HTTP error happening and not an error in your code, what are the `textStatus` and `errorThrown` if you include those parameters in your handler (i.e., `error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown )`)

Comment: textstatus = parseerror and errorThrown is Unexpected token <(..)

Comment: Just realized that in the response text, it is returning the html as part of the object... Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseerror` and `Unexpected token` mean exactly what you suspected: you asked jQuery to parse the result as JSON, but it doesn't have valid JSON (it has some HTML to work with too).

Make sure the result is valid JSON (or, if you want the HTML, don't tell jQuery to parse it as JSON) and it'll come through as a successful transaction.

Comment: Thanks VoteyDisciple... I see that now.. Accepting your answer as soon as it will allow me to do so..